# Unable to close a singleton window from the background script in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How does my background script close one of the windows it opened? When I try using the "win" returned from a `chrome.app.window.create(` call, it throws the error that the window was not created by "chrome.app.window", but it was! (I know this because the call to that successfully creates the window. It is a singleton which I think might be what's causing this.

Is there a way to get the window by its ID?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling close() on created_window or created_window.contentWindow?

Comment: How do I do that when I can't even get a reference to it? I tried using `chrome.tabs.getSelected` but it says I don't have permissions for that even though mu manifest has the "tabs" permission (but it is an app). What API/interface do I use to get that reference?

Comment: I still cannot get a reference to that window after the first time I created it. But I know that the window is valid because in the content script I passed the current window back to the background script and it is a valid AppWindow: `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(
     function(page)
     { 
      page.console.dir( chrome.app.window.current()  ); 
     }
    );`

Comment: You shouldn't have to "get a reference to that window after ... creat[ing] it." You should keep the AppWindow returned in the create() callback. That's the reference, and you should keep it.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. When I create the window and add a callback function to that call, it throws the error and gives me a null window reference in the callback. There is **no** window returned from the create call. One thing to note: I give each window a name (this stays the same on each app launch for that `window.create` call)

Answer (score 0):

Call `close()` on the window returned to the callback of `chrome.app.window.create`.

You can test this for different window types (e.g. singleton and non singleton) by modifying the [window-state/window.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/window-state/window.js) file where window.create is called to be:

```
chrome.app.window.create('window.html',
                         optionsDictionary,
                         function (w) {
                           setTimeout(function () {
                                        w.close()
                                      },
                                      1000);
                         });
```